# How to add cordova plugins to ionic project without internet?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. And I want to add cordova plugins to my ionic project.
 I want to add them offline. I have tried a lot on solution online but i have not yet found. 
Is there any way or not.? if yes then how to do it ?

Comment: use this command cordova plugin add your-plugin-tgz-or-zipfile-path --save

Answer (score 1):

You can't add cordova plugins in offline mode.

When you run the commands through command prompt then plugin will be downloaded to your ionic project.

[Refer this link for how to install the cordova plugins](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/)

You can also download custom plugins, anyhow you need internet to download custom plugins.

[Refer this link for how to download cordova custom plugins](http://ngcordova.com/build/)

Comment: You can add a plugin locally if it was already downloaded. `cordova plugin add /path/to/plugin --save`

Comment: @johnborges ya that only i told, any how we need internet connection to download that custom plugins later we can install.